# Bash: $-related problems when reading package names from file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, apt-get

I have a file `apt.list` which stores APT package names - one package per line.
I use the contents of this file the following way:

```
entries=`cat apt.list`
for entry in $entries
do
  apt-get install $entry
done
```

Everything works fine except in the case when package name is given as, e.g.

```
linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

What should I do to make $-containing entries be interpreted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't parse `cat` output, use a proper loop around the file to parse each line output.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    apt-get install "$line"
done<apt.list
```

Comment: Please Inian, wait a second! I'll try

Comment: OK, it is parsed correctly. Just one small problem. It says that the package `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` not found. But it works when I type it directly without reading from file

Comment: @DraganMarinic: `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` does not seem to be a valid package name. the part within `$(uname -r)` need to b expanded to some value as it inside command substitution, after that it will be `linux-headers-13.14.1` (for example). Please re-check the file why it is not expanded